# Node npm start error port listen on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, express

I generate new express app and when im click npm start and then ctrl+c to exit and try again to do npm start i get this error:

```
Error:listen EADDRINUSE
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is in an app. Your process can detach from console or spawn another process, which continue to bind the port.

Comment: So how i can exit the server and stop the port from being used?

Comment: killall node =) Or handly, with ps x | grep node

Comment: But what, every time im click ctrl+c to cancel i will need to kill node too?

Comment: i recommend you to investigate the app firstly and then ask for help. I described just one of the probably reasons

Comment: This is the init app from express generator with port 3000

Comment: you can look throw process, binded on 3000 port after exiting app with lsof -i tcp:3000

Answer (score 0):

It happens when another server is running in the same port that you are trying to open a new server